# CakePHP 3 replace content in a div with data returned from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.x

My end to load goal is to load more items from the database when the page gets close to the bottom of the page. I have created page that load 6 charts from the database to start. I wrote this jquery JavaScript

```
<script>
(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
       if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 0) {
          loadmore();
       }
    });
    divID = $('.chartArea>div:last-child').find('div').attr('id');
    divID = divID.substr(6);
    divID = divID-6;
    function loadmore() {
         $.ajax({`
         `url: "<?php echo $this->Url->build(['action'=>'chartsTest']);?>",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'text',
            data:  {'id': divID },
            success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
                $('.chartArea').html(data);
            }
        });
    };
})();
</script>
```

That is all working except `$('.chartArea').html(data);` which returns the whole HTML document of `<!DOCTYPE html>` and inserts it into the div chartArea

This part of the page affected by the first database call and the JavaScript

HTML

```
<div class="lay2col chartArea">
<?php foreach($items as $chart) { 
    $card = new \App\Model\Entity\Card();
    $card->content_type = (object)[ 'name' => 'chart' ];
    $card->content_id = $chart->slug;
    $card->chart = $chart;
?>
    <div>
        <div id="chart-<?=$chart->id?>" class="card-chart card-half card content" title="<?=$card->override('title') ?: $card->chart->title?>">
            <?=$this->element('cards/chart', ['card' => $card])?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is what I have in my controller

```
public function chartsTest() {
    $this->loadModel('Charts');
    if($this->request->is('ajax')) { 
        $chartID = $this->request->data['id'];
        $items = $this->Charts->find('all')->where(['Charts.active'=>true, 'Charts.id >=' => $chartID]);
        $items->order(['Charts.id' => 'desc']);

        $this->autoFilter($items);
        $moreCharts='';
        foreach($items as $chart) { 
            $card = new \App\Model\Entity\Card();
            $card->content_type = (object)[ 'name' => 'chart' ];
            $card->content_id = $chart->slug;
            $card->chart = $chart;
            $moreCharts. = '<div>
                <div id="chart-'.$chart->id.'" class="card-chart card-half card content" title="'.$card->chart->title.'">
                    <a href="/the-palce/charts-and-graphs/'.$card->chart->slug.'">
                        <img class="twox" src="'.$card->image_path.'" alt="'.$card->altTag.'">
                        </div>
                        <div class="graphic-pill">
                            <span class="pill">Chart</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btm-info">
                            <p class="summary">'.$card->chart->title.'</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>';
        };
        $this->set([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $moreCharts
        ]);
    }  else {
        $items = $this->Charts->find('all')->where(['Charts.active'=>true])->limit(6);
        $items->order(['Charts.id' => 'desc']);
        $this->set([
            'page_title' => 'Charts and Graphs',
            'page'       => 'charts and graphs',
            'items'      => $items
        ]);
    } 
}
```

So I must be missing something because my `$('.chartArea').html(data);` in my JavaScript function returns the whole `<!DOCTYPE html>` when Im expecting just the data inside the variable `$moreCharts`. The odd thing is if check the console I can see

```
$dataForView = [
&#039;success&#039; =&gt; true,
&#039;data&#039; =&gt; &#039;
            &lt;div&gt;
                &lt;div id=&quot;chart-73&quot; class=&quot;card-chart card-half card content&quot; title=&quot;title&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;a href=&quot;/the-place/slug&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;img class=&quot;twox&quot; src=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;graphic-pill&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;span class=&quot;pill&quot;&gt;Chart&lt;/span&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;btm-info&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;p class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.&lt;/p&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/a&gt;
                &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div&gt;
                &lt;div id=&quot;chart-72&quot; class=&quot;card-chart card-half card content&quot; title=&quot;title&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;a href=&quot;/the-place/slug&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;img class=&quot;twox&quot; src=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;graphic-pill&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;span class=&quot;pill&quot;&gt;Chart&lt;/span&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;btm-info&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;p class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.&lt;/p&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/a&gt;
                &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div&gt;
                &lt;div id=&quot;chart-71&quot; class=&quot;card-chart card-half card content&quot; title=&quot;title&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;a href=&quot;/the-place/slug&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;img class=&quot;twox&quot; src=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;graphic-pill&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;span class=&quot;pill&quot;&gt;Chart&lt;/span&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;btm-info&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;p class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.&lt;/p&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div&gt;
                &lt;div id=&quot;chart-70&quot; class=&quot;card-chart card-half card content&quot; title=&quot;title&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;a href=&quot;/the-place/slug&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;img class=&quot;twox&quot; src=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;graphic-pill&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;span class=&quot;pill&quot;&gt;Chart&lt;/span&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;btm-info&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;p class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.&lt;/p&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div&gt;
                &lt;div id=&quot;chart-69&quot; class=&quot;card-chart card-half card content&quot; title=&quot;title&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;a href=&quot;/the-place/slug&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;img class=&quot;twox&quot; src=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;graphic-pill&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;span class=&quot;pill&quot;&gt;Chart&lt;/span&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;btm-info&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;p class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.&lt;/p&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div&gt;
                &lt;div id=&quot;chart-68&quot; class=&quot;card-chart card-half card content&quot; title=&quot;title&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;a href=&quot;/the-place/slug&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;img class=&quot;twox&quot; src=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;graphic-pill&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;span class=&quot;pill&quot;&gt;Chart&lt;/span&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;btm-info&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;p class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.&lt;/p&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div&gt;
                &lt;div id=&quot;chart-67&quot; class=&quot;card-chart card-half card content&quot; title=&quot;title&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;a href=&quot;/the-place/slug&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;img class=&quot;twox&quot; src=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;graphic-pill&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;span class=&quot;pill&quot;&gt;Chart&lt;/span&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;btm-info&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;p class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.&lt;/p&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div&gt;
                &lt;div id=&quot;chart-66&quot; class=&quot;card-chart card-half card content&quot; title=&quot;title&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;a href=&quot;/the-place/slug&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;img class=&quot;twox&quot; src=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;graphic-pill&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;span class=&quot;pill&quot;&gt;Chart&lt;/span&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;btm-info&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;p class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.&lt;/p&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div&gt;
                &lt;div id=&quot;chart-65&quot; class=&quot;card-chart card-half card content&quot; title=&quot;title&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;a href=&quot;/the-place/slug&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;img class=&quot;twox&quot; src=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;graphic-pill&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;span class=&quot;pill&quot;&gt;Chart&lt;/span&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;btm-info&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;p class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.&lt;/p&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div&gt;
                &lt;div id=&quot;chart-664quot; class=&quot;card-chart card-half card content&quot; title=&quot;title&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;a href=&quot;/the-place/slug&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;img class=&quot;twox&quot; src=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;graphic-pill&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;span class=&quot;pill&quot;&gt;Chart&lt;/span&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;btm-info&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;p class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.&lt;/p&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div&gt;
                &lt;div id=&quot;chart-63&quot; class=&quot;card-chart card-half card content&quot; title=&quot;title&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;a href=&quot;/the-place/slug&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;img class=&quot;twox&quot; src=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;graphic-pill&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;span class=&quot;pill&quot;&gt;Chart&lt;/span&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;btm-info&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;p class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.&lt;/p&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div&gt;
                &lt;div id=&quot;chart-62&quot; class=&quot;card-chart card-half card content&quot; title=&quot;title&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;a href=&quot;/the-place/slug&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;img class=&quot;twox&quot; src=&quot;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;graphic-pill&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;span class=&quot;pill&quot;&gt;Chart&lt;/span&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                        &lt;div class=&quot;btm-info&quot;&gt;
                            &lt;p class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.&lt;/p&gt;
                        &lt;/div&gt;
                    &lt;/a&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
```

So I can see from the console that it is grabbing the next 6 charts but I need to know to isolate them add add/replace the ones in div chartArea.

Comment: Remove  dataType: 'text' from your ajax call. and check what are you getting in your network tab of your inspect element.

Comment: Hey Sehdev, I removed dataType and it still returns the whole document

Comment: Seems like you're probably using the default layout even for Ajax views. Lots of Google hits out there for `cakephp 3 ajax layout`.

Comment: Change  $this->set([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $moreCharts
        ]); to $this->response->body(json_encode([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $moreCharts
        ]));
           return $this->response;

Comment: Had a 2 fold problem but figured it out last night I had changed the JavaScript from `success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
                $('.chartArea').html(data);
            }` to `success: function(response) { 
    //success
    console.log(response); 
    $('.chartArea').html(response);
    }` and in controller I added `$this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);` and changed ` $this->set([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $moreCharts
        ]);` to `$status=$moreCharts;
   $this->response->body($status);
   return $this->response; `